# UL certified, DMX compatible programmable LED controller

Tags: led

We're doing a commercial LED installation with some industrial-grade LEDs that are DMX compatible. We need a controller that receive real-time input from a computer to change it's color/brightness/etc. It's a small number of lights in an indoor space. Ideally it uses WiFi, but we can do a hardwired connection without much difficulty. Everything I've looked at so far is either a hobbyist machine or a light show player.

Answer (score 1):

I gather from your question that you have not worked with DMX controlled LEDs before. As a theater technician, I have used DMX controlled LEDs, and have to use a DMX controller like the one you are describing. Personally, I have worked with [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00WG3HV4W) from Joyland to power up to 3 5m strips of RGBW LED tape.

To provide some more insight, I will assume you are using RGBW (4 color) LED tape. To control this via DMX (also called DMX512), you will need a 4 channel controller like the one I linked above. The controllers get a 12v power supply in, as well as DMX data through ethernet (RJ45) ports. This means you will also need a DMX512(5-pin XLR) - ethernet (RJ45) adapters. You can daisy-chain the controllers with Cat5e or Cat6 cables. To control them via DMX, you will have to assign addresses to the controllers control them from a DMX control device (such as a lighting console). If you didn't understand most of this second paragraph, I would suggest doing more research on DMX control or talking to someone who has worked with DMX control before.